# Can a windows service be ran multiple times (using different settings)?

Tags: windows, service

Can a windows service (possibly copied to multiple locations) be ran multiple times using different configurations (say for instance if the service supports commandline arguments)?

A service seems to be only installed once since the name has to be unique.

Is this scenario possible and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the basis for "svchost.exe", it is just given different service names and parameters.

This will help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890

Comment: Interesting. A question though: the KB gives as an example that it makes a service from 'notepad' which inherently is not a service but just a plain exe. Does this trick also work for real services?

Comment: AFAIK its meant to illustrate that ANY program can be run as a service.. although I would use some form of daemon myself.

Comment: Or to say it differently, starting multiple instances of a service is perfectly possible.  It just depends on you setting it up, and the application actually supporting it.  One semi-common example is MSDE.  MSDE allows you to install several instances each as a separate service.

Comment: Notepad doesn't actually work as a service anyway; it fails to tell the SCM that it is up and running in a timely fashion...

Answer (score 1):

If by multiple instances of the same service, you mean different instances of the same executable, then sure. You just need to create multiple "service" entries for it in the service table, with different names and different command line options.

Grizly seems to be talking about a different thing, where several services run inside the *same* process, typically an instance of `svchost.exe`. This necessitates that they use the same executable, though each service hosted by `svchost` appears to specify a DLL and (optionally) a ServiceMain entrypoint in the `Parameters` subkey of the service key. (Of course, the details of `svchost.exe` usage don't appear to be documented -- probably to keep people from trying to do crazy stuff like loading some version of the .NET framework into one of the system-critical instances, which would eventually lead to some other service trying to load a *different* version of the framework into the same one, and that would be a complete mess...)